# gwt splitlayout insert widgets to layout

Tags: gwt, layout

I've created the splitlayout and created a new ListBox.

```
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.addItem("foo");
        lb.addItem("bar");
        lb.addItem("baz");
        lb.addItem("toto");
        lb.addItem("tintin");


        SplitLayoutPanel p = new SplitLayoutPanel();
        p.addWest(new HTML("list"), 128);           
        p.add(new HTML("details"));
        RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        rp.add(p);
```

Now how do i insert 'lb' to the west of 'p' ?
I tried 'p.addWest(lb,pixel);' instead of 'p.addWest(new HTML("list"), 128);' it looks and behaves terrible !! Please help

Comment: and what is the question? seemingly you CAN insert lb to the west of p, but don't like the way it looks and behaves... I am confused. Usually you wouldn't add lb directly to the west of p, but instead wrapped it into some kind of panel (if only to give it some room and size).

Comment: I'm new to GWT and I want to know what is the right way to do the above... The way I did it is not good or even wrong

Comment: the way you did it is the only way... no need to ask for any other. As I said, it would be easier to change the looks and behavior if you wrapped lb into some panel.

Comment: Side note since you are new to gwt, I would recommend getting comfortable with UiBinder. It will make styling the widgets much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    lb.addItem("foo");
    lb.addItem("bar");
    lb.addItem("baz");
    lb.addItem("toto");
    lb.addItem("tintin");


    SplitLayoutPanel p = new SplitLayoutPanel();
    p.addWest(lb, 100);
    p.addWest(new HTML("list"), 128);           
    p.add(new HTML("details"));
    RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
    rp.add(p);
```

In SplitLayoutPanel/DockLayoutPanel you cannot add widgets after you add your center widget i.e., after you use the api `splitLayoutPanel.add( Widget w )`, So you have to do all the operations before hand or re layout the entire panel by clearing it first.

Comment: Hey, here you've added 2 west panels.
I want to use the west panel I have and put there info... I put the listbox in verticalpanel and added it to the west, it's fine.
now how do I use the center widget to write on the HTML object I've created ??

Comment: In simple terms you can't. Thats how split panel works